# Run-time error -2147467259 (80004005): This document can not be checked in

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, office365, onedrive

I'm getting the below error while the macro tries to "Check-in" an excel file to Onedrive sharepoint.

Can someone help me to fix this and check-in through the macro?

Syntax used:

```
Workbooks("Test.xlsb").checkin SaveChanges:=True, Comments:="Testing"
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to use the [Workbook.CanCheckIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.cancheckin) property which returns true if Microsoft Excel can check in a specified workbook to a server.

```
Sub CheckInOut(strWkbCheckIn As String) 
 
 ' Determine if workbook can be checked in. 
 If Workbooks(strWkbCheckIn).CanCheckIn = True Then 
   Workbooks(strWkbCheckIn).CheckIn 
   MsgBox strWkbCheckIn & " has been checked in." 
 Else 
   MsgBox "This file cannot be checked in " & _ 
          "at this time. Please try again later." 
 End If 
 
End Sub
```